# Sharding on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections in mongodb:
user collection

```
{
_id:xxxxxx,
friendList:[12345,67899,57889],//list of ids of friends
readBooks:[bookid1,bookid2],
wanttoread:[bookid5,bookid6]
}
```

friends collection

```
{ _id:12345,
readBooks:[bookid3,bookid5],
wantToread:[bookid1]}
```

I have another collection `books` which gives the name and details of a book for the id.
I want to do sharding for this in mongodb, based on `readBook` or `wanttoread`. If they have the same books, the data goes to the same shard.

I searched about this, but I couldn't find a way to shard based on array. Is there any way i can do it? or do I need to create another collection like

```
 {id: userid or friend id,bookId:bookid}
```

and shard based on bookId.

Comment: You cannot do multikey shard indexes atm

Answer (score 0):

you can only use one shard key, and you can not change it after you choose one.

I'd suggest to shard over collection-id which has the largest cardinality (largest number of documents).

[MongoDB Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)